# Позиция курсора консоли в Java

Tags: java, cursor, консоль

Вот сейчас думаю напишу-ка консольный движок на Java для крестиков-ноликов, в C# реализовал довольно легко, ибо там есть управление курсором, но с Java возникла проблема

```
public void cellDraw() {

    //отрисовка зависит от свойств

    //Пустая ячейка IsBlank
    if(this.IsBlank == true) {

        System.out.println("-----");
        System.out.println("-   -");
        System.out.println("-----");

    }
    //Крестик IsTic
    else if (this.IsTic == true) {

        System.out.println("-----");
        System.out.println("- X -");
        System.out.println("-----");
    }
```

Выводится примитивные блоки из дефисов, соответственно надо, чтобы следующий блок начинался с N - позиции строки в консоли, аналогия в C# `Console.SetCursorPosition(x,y)`.

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать используя управляющие последовательности, о которых можно почитать, например, тут: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences

На Java это можно реализовать примерно таким методом:

```java
public static void setCursorPorision(int x, int y) {
    final char escCode = 0x1B;
    System.out.print(String.format("%c[%d;%df", escCode, y, x));
}
```

PS: Похоже этот метод не работает в Windows, увы.